# Can you use Data Factory to copy from S3 to Azure and pipe the results to BCP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, azure

Suppose I have a ton of data on S3, and I want to move it to SQL tables in Azure. I've written a Powershell script that will do this once I have the files.

One way to do it would be to just simply copy the files over to Azure, and then execute the script. Is there a more efficient way to do it, one that doesn't require fully copying them all first, and then inserting them into tables?

Answer (score 0):

you can also try to combine both storages in 1xVM...

Just an Idea:
in Azure 1x VM
mount: Azure Blobstorage
mount: S3 Bucket

start: copy from S3 to your new Azure Storage. 
Please watch out, performance and costs between this cloud providers

For Example: The Download Bandwith on Azure site is limited and you need to pay for more bandwith...

The Cloud Recommended way is: DataFactory, please read:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/data-factory/connector-amazon-simple-storage-service

good luck and best regards